# mysql count total of muliple columns

Tags: mysql, sql

hi i have a table as follow:

user table

```
id  val1 val2 val3
1    2    3    2
2    0    0    1
```

i would like to know how to count value from columns val1,val2,val3 where id = 1 ? which means 
for `id = 1` total would be 7 and for `id = 2` total would be 1. Most of SO example count the entire columns for all ids.My solution as follow seems not get preferred result

```
select count(*) as tot
from (
select val1 as total from user
where id=1
union
select val2 as total from user
where id=1
union
select val3 as total from user
where id=1
) as x
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you need to sum the column values for each user id. This will do:

```
select id, coalesce(val1, 0) + coalesce(val2, 0) + coalesce(val3, 0) 
from user
```

Notice that coalesce is a SQL ANSI defined function, thus, it will work on other DBMSs as well. You can use `IFNULL()`, but that will only work in MySQL.

Answer (score 6):

You can simply add the columns together:

```
SELECT val1 + val2 + val3 FROM user WHERE id = 1
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9f06c/1/0).

---

**UPDATE**

To exclude `NULL` values, use MySQL's [`IFNULL()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull) function:

```
SELECT IFNULL(val1,0) + IFNULL(val2,0) + IFNULL(val3,0) FROM user WHERE id = 1
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9f06c/2/0).

Comment: some val have null how can i not to include that in count cause the result return NULL.Thanks

Comment: @zlippr: Use MySQL's [`IFNULL()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull) function, as shown in my update above.