# mysql count popular post vote

Tags: mysql

hi i have an Mysql table as follow,

```
post_id  | user_id  |   status | date_created
  2          2         funny     20121022120627
  2          3         lame      20121023120627
  3          1         useful    20121023120627
  3          3         lame      20121023120627
  3          4         useful    20121023120627
```

now i need a query on getting a post_id for popular post based on status count.
Means post with many status for the day.Example `post_id = 3` will be popular since it has 3 status voted, so i can find the owner of this post on post table.Thanks!!

Comment: COUNT(*) + GROUP BY + ORDER BY + LIMIT --- this is all what you need

Comment: @zerkms but mysql says ;-) `mysql> COUNT(*) + GROUP BY + ORDER BY + LIMIT;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'COUNT(*) + GROUP BY + ORDER BY + LIMIT' at line 1`

Comment: @AdrianCornish he is mention that we can find an result by using what he suggested not the exactly one!!

Comment: @zlippr Read my comment again :-)

Comment: @zerkms hi it would easy if you can provide me a query for me to perform test.Thanks

Comment: @AdrianCornish sorry dude not get it, seems there is syntax error.

Comment: @zlippr zerkms is trying to help you find your own answer rather than just giving it. Think about it, look at what he said and try and find your own solution especially since you never gave your own effort on trying to do it

Comment: what if two `post_id` have same no. of status ?

Comment: @AdrianCornish fren i got try yesterday http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13016623/mysql-count-total-of-muliple-columns but still facing same problems.Thanks

Comment: @diEcho there is where date_created comes in. We can choose the latest one

Comment: @zlippr does popular means your status is useful

Comment: @BhavikShah if not useful also it will attract someone!! for sure user wont vote without reason

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one,

```
SELECT post_id
FROM tableName
GROUP BY post_ID
HAVING COUNT(*) = 
(
    SELECT MAX(x.counts)
    FROM
    (
        SELECT post_id, COUNT(*) counts
        FROM tableName
        GROUP BY post_id
    ) x
)
```

## [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/07975/3)

basically, I won't recomment to use limit here since there are possibilities that certain `Post_ID` has the same number of votes.

Comment: Thanks, also thanks for introduce SQLFiddle, look nice to use, similar to JSFiddle

Answer (score 0):

```
select t1.post_id,max(t1.countstatus) 
from 
(select post_id,count(*) as countstatus 
  from table_name
   where status='useful' group by post_id)as t1 
 group by t1.id ;
```

try this
I am assuming that popular vote means status='useful'